# How to place a specific span in center of a div?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div that contains 3 span so how can i place a span in center of div using css class ( Laptop/Mobile both case need auto center )

```
    <div class="caption" >
    <i class="fa fa-sun-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Day <span class="day">1</span>
    <span class="dot">Happy</span>
    <span class="t-day">Oct. 26, 2016</span>
    </div>
```

Here i need class="t-day" in center. Please help for( mobile and laptop auto center)

Comment: What do you mean by *center*? Vertically, horizontally or both?

Comment: What is your CSS to go along with your HTML?

Comment: Aside --- there is no **t-date** class

Comment: sorry that is t-day

Answer (score 0):

you can use the CSS property: `vertical-align:middle;` and `text-align: center;` 
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp

Comment: vertical-align:middle; and text-align: center; not working.

Comment: How can i use.please let me know??

Comment: only works for `display:inline-block` elements (as well as `display:table-cell`). ---
doesn't work for floated elements.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the CSS:
(If the box doesn't align vertically exactly on middle, you can use the padding or line-height property)

```
.caption {
width: 100%;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
padding-bottom: 1px;
border: solid 1px red;
}
```